# Cannot load in R with dyn.load a dll compiled with Visual Studio

Tags: c, r, visual-studio-2012, dll

I cannot load dlls that I compile with Visual Studio in Win XP sp3 or Win7. I set the current directory in the path environment. When I try to dyn.load it I get the error message:

"
Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) : 
  unable to load shared object 'C:/Documents and Settings//[.....]//sampleDLL.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified module could not be found.
"

Obviously the dll is there, the error refers to something else missing.

I can call the dll from C. Below I attach a small example of a dll that cannot be loaded in R.
I am running out of ideas. Can someone help?

file sampleDLL.c

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "SampleDLL.h"

double PowerOf2 (double UserNumber)
{
    printf("Complete the Power of 2");
    return UserNumber * UserNumber;
}

double PowerOf3 (double UserNumber)
{
    printf("Complete the Power of 3");
    return UserNumber * UserNumber * UserNumber;
}

double CircleArea (double UserRadius)
{
    printf("Complete the CircleArea");
    return UserRadius * UserRadius * PI;
}

double CircleCircum (double UserRadius)
{
    printf("Complete the CircleCircum");
    return 2 * UserRadius * PI;
}

void MyFunc(char ** strInput)
{
    printf("Complete the MyFunc");
    MessageBox(0, L"Hi Viet from C", L"C Program", 0);
}
```

end sampleDLL.c

sampleDLL.h

```
#ifdef SAMPLEDLL_EXPORTS
#define SAMPLEDLL_API __declspec(dllexport) 
#else
#define SAMPLEDLL_API __declspec(dllimport) 
#endif

#define PI 3.1415

SAMPLEDLL_API double  PowerOf2 (double UserNumber);
SAMPLEDLL_API double  PowerOf3 (double UserNumber);
SAMPLEDLL_API double  CircleArea (double UserRadius);
SAMPLEDLL_API double  CircleCircum (double UserRadius);
SAMPLEDLL_API void  MyFunc(char ** strInput);
```

end sampleDLL.h

Comment: Why do you expect this to work? [R Installation and Administration: Appendix D The Windows toolset](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html#The-Windows-toolset) says, "This appendix contains a lot of prescriptive comments. They are here as a result of bitter experience. Please do not report problems to the R mailing lists unless you have followed all the prescriptions.". So my first idea is: skim the manuals (at least the table of contents).

Comment: Also, the unix-style file separator `/` is being used rather than the Windows-style file separator `\`; perhaps this is related. Spaces in paths can cause problems as well. But really, you should follow @JoshuaUlrich's advice.

Comment: Thank you both! Actually the documents refer to compilig the C code through R, if I understand well. All I want to do is to compile a dll independently and then call it from R. I can do it in FORTRAN, I imagine I should be able to do it in C?